# How to crop an image using codeigniter?

Tags: image, codeigniter, crop

I have tried to crop an image which is uploaded using CodeIgniter. I have used library upload function for uploading the image.How can i crop the image after uploading and is there any method to crop an image?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Comment: @Alwin Please refer it first [https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/image_lib.html]

Comment: or show me your code so we can help you out

Comment: @M.Hemant Thank you for sharing me the link

Answer (score 0):

```
$file_name="uploaded_image";
$path="folder path to ur file";
 $config = array();
$config['source_image'] = $path . $file_name;
        $config['new_image'] = $path."/crop/" . $data['file_name'];

        $config['width'] = 350;

        $config['height'] = 250;
        $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
```

try this